# Book about a group of kids abducted from various historical disasters and then live in a time loop of 9/11 have to stop neo-nazis

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

This was a book where several kids who died in several historical disasters were given a choice by an old man about if they wanted to die in that disaster or come with him and be sort-of "time police", the only catch is that they would be locked into that role. There was a boy who was on the Titanic, a girl who was on one of the 9/11 planes, and I think one or two more.

They are taken to this secret hideout which is in New York during a time loop of 9/11. When they are there, every day is the same day, September 11th 2001, and the reason for this is because it keeps them away from prying eyes. The current timeline, not the time loop, is in the future, where time travel technology is invented, and the old man and the kids serve to stop anyone from misusing time travel.

In the current time, the future, a group of heavily armed Neo-Nazis raid a museum, maybe the natural history museum?, to abscond with the first time machine, which is on display, so they can go back and have the Nazis win World War 2. The Neo-Nazis succeed in their goal and go to Hitler's bunker in the Winter and show him all of their future technology.

This book was part of the series, and the second book concerned dinosaurs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The *TimeRiders* series by Alex Scarrow, first published 2010.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TimeRiders):

> Liam O'Connor **should have died at sea in 1912.**
>
> Maddy Carter should have died on a plane in 2010.
>
> Sal Vikram should have died in a fire in 2026.
>
> Yet moments before death, someone mysteriously appeared and said, 'Take my hand ...'
>
> But Liam, Maddy and Sal aren't rescued. They are recruited by an agency that no one knows exists, with only one purpose—to fix broken history. Because time travel is here, and there are those who would go back in time and change the past. That's why the TimeRiders exist: to protect us. To stop time travel from destroying the world... [...]
>
> They operate from their field office underneath an archway of the Williamsburg Bridge in New York City in **a two-day 'Time Bubble', on September 10 and 11, 2001.**

---

Found with the Google query `scifi book time travel 9/11 loop`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think that the question would be super hard to answer.